# deriving from class containing member who's template argument is the base class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11

sorry if this is a duplicate, it's been fruitless finding anything on this scenario. This is not a name resolution problem per se, more a template / structure problem.

Per the title, there is a situation that looks like this:

```
template< typename T > struct X;

struct Y {
    X< Y > & xy;
    Y( X< Y > & _xy ) : xy( _xy ) {}
    virtual ~Y();
};

template< typename T > struct X {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<Y, T>::value, "T is not a Y" );
    T member_t;
    X() : member_t( *this ) {}
    virtual ~X();
}

struct DY : Y {
    int test2 = 2;
    void tester1 () {
        // int t1 = static_cast< X< DY > >( xy ).test1;
        // fails: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'X<Y>' to 'const X<DY>&'
    }
};

struct DX : X< DY > {
    int test1 = 1;
    void tester2 () {
        int t2 = member_t.test2; // perfectly ok, no problems.
    }
};
```

The full error list is a cascade of nastiness that does make sense, mostly. What I don't understand is how to deal with situations in `tester1` - a class that is to be derived from, uses itself in a template of one of its members, and the derived class must use itself in the companion class template (X -> DX). Here it is for your enjoyment folks... (sorry in advance my line numbers will be slightly different than formatted here)

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct X<Y>':
main.cpp:35:44:   required from here
main.cpp:23:5: error: static assertion failed: T is not a Y
     static_assert( std::is_base_of<Y, T>::value, "T is not a Y" );
     ^
main.cpp: In member function 'void DY::tester1()':
main.cpp:35:44: error: no matching function for call to 'X<DY>::X(X<Y>&)'
        int t1 = static_cast< X< DY > >( xy ).test1;
                                            ^
main.cpp:35:44: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:25:5: note: X<T>::X() [with T = DY]
     X ()
     ^
main.cpp:25:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp:21:31: note: constexpr X<DY>::X(const X<DY>&)
 template< typename T > struct X
                               ^
main.cpp:21:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'X<Y>' to 'const X<DY>&'
```

I understand perfectly why `X<Y>` cannot be converted to `X<DY>` directly - they are 'unrelated' classes. Is there an elegant way to perform this conversion in the general case where we know for a fact `Y` is a base class to `DY`?

My guess at the moment is to implement a constructor `X<DY>::X( X<Y> )` (or a similar operator), per one of the compiler notes, but that may not be possible if `Y` for any reason cannot be copied... So `X<DY>::member_y` this way would have to be copied from some `X<Y>::member_y`, or could it be elegantly statically cast? Not sure...

---

**Aim**

There are two classes, `X` and `Y`, and they have the relationship that `X` will accept `Y` or some derivative thereof as a template argument. This is, for example, to coordinate behavior common to `Y`-like objects within some container `X`.

Using a derived `Y` and just `X` is self-evident (to me anyway) how to do. The challenge is to have the 'coordinated behavior' itself extensible. The above is an attempt at doing this by making a derived `X` (`DX`) which clearly does not work if we ever need to refer to the `X`-type from the derived `Y`-type.

Comment: Even if Y is the base of DY, there's no enforced relation between X<Y> and X<DY>. Even if you define them as above, theoretically compiler is allowed to store X<Y>::member_t and X<DY>::member_t at different offsets due to padding. Btw, how would you construct DY? Your X<Y>& would not accept X<DY>...

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem lol... I have no idea. Is there any way at all to perform conversions / casting of template parameter types?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

template <typename T> struct Foo {};

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;

   A& aRef = b;  // OK

   Foo<A> foo_a;
   Foo<B> foo_b;

   Foo<A>& foo_aRef = foo_b; // Not OK.
}
```

`B` is a sub-type of `A`. That does not make `Foo<B>` a sub-type of `Foo<A>`.

The problem you are seeing in the line:

```
  int t1 = static_cast< X< DY > >( xy ).test1;
```

is worse.

`xy` is of type `X<Y>`. You are trying to cast it to `X<DY>`.

That will be analogous to trying to cast `Foo<A>` to `Foo<B>` in my example code.

I am unable to suggest a fix since it's not clear to me what you are trying accomplish with your classes.

Comment: In essence if you have two classes X and Y, with the relationship that X is accepting Y as a template parameter, and I wish to make it possible to extend both X and Y with derived classes to preserve that relationship / behavior in X and Y. I don't doubt there is a simpler way to express that but so far I've become stuck with this direction and out of ideas...

Comment: @XerenNarcy, that does not explain what you are trying to do in `DY::tester1()`. More importantly, it's not clear what's the use case you are trying to solve. It feels like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks, I've added a better explanation of what the aim is here, hopefully that isn't the XY problem again (please do say so if it still is, I'll go have a long think on it before asking again).

Comment: @XerenNarcy, that still sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: On top of it all, `test1` is a member of `DX`, not `X<DY>`.